# Does having app screen with most of the area covered with black color save battery?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

Lets assume my home screen have UIView that is 80% black in color. Does this help to save battery? I know backlight of iPhone will on no matter what is the screen color is. But having more black pixels make the battery less stressful?

Comment: Interesting question. But I assume it makes very little difference. What drains battery is what's happening in the background: animations, videos, server requests, loading files, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thats true for OLED displays only, but it's LCD display in iPhone. So answer - black screen will not save you battery.

Comment: So it means in LCD screens the power it drains to light up a pixel doesn't depends on the color?

Comment: yes, screen backlight is always the same. The only way - it's reduce the backlight (screen bright)